Why is blenders projection matrix off by a certain factor?
Given the vertices of a plane, I should be able to match the rendering from blender and a 3D->2D projection of the positions of the vertices based on the MVP matrix from blender. 
My problem is,that the elements P[0,0] and P[1,1] from the projection matrix are of by a factor of ~0.8 and I am clueless where this factor comes from.
Here is my setup:
Blender:
I have a simple blender scene with a plane of a specific shape and a camera. I use freestyle to get the contour of the plane in my final render. Camera parameters are (mostly) taken from a real-world camera and have the following settings:
Output:
Resolution X = 2592px
Resolution Y = 1944 px
Aspect X = 1.0
Aspect Y = 1.0

Camera:
Type: Perspective
Focal  Length: 8mm
Lens Unit: Millimeters
Shift X: 0.0
Shift Y: 0.0
Clip Start: 0.1m
Clip End: 1000m
Sensor Fit: Horizontal
Width: 5.702mm

Here is the code to get the needed matrices:
import bpy
import numpy as np


def main():
    render = bpy.context.scene.render
    contour = bpy.data.objects["contour "]
    camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]

    model_matrix = np.array(contour .matrix_world)
    view_matrix = np.array(camera.matrix_world.inverted())

    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    projection_matrix = np.array(
        camera.calc_matrix_camera(
            depsgraph,
            x=render.resolution_x,
            y=render.resolution_y,
            scale_x=render.pixel_aspect_x,
            scale_y=render.pixel_aspect_y,
        )
    )

    print(f"FOV: {camera.data.angle_x}")

    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    print("Model Matrix: ")
    print(model_matrix)
    print("====================================\n")

    print("View Matrix: ")
    print(view_matrix)
    print("====================================\n")

    print("Projection Matrix: ")
    print(projection_matrix)
    print("====================================\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

In a simple setup with the plane at world origin and the camera above it, looking down, I get the following output:
FOV: 0.6846855878829956
Model Matrix: 
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
====================================

View Matrix: 
[[ 1. -0.  0. -0.]
 [-0.  1. -0.  0.]
 [ 0. -0.  1. -1.]
 [-0.  0. -0.  1.]]
====================================

Projection Matrix: 
[[ 2.8060329   0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          3.74137735  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -1.00019991 -0.20002   ]
 [ 0.          0.         -1.          0.        ]]
====================================

3D->2D Projection
With the vertices of the plane as 3D points and the matrices I should now be able to produce a projection, which fits the blender render output. I tried to add some comments to make the code more understandable
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def main():
    resolution = np.array([2592, 1944])

    mvp = projection_matrix @ view_matrix @ model_matrix

    points = np.hstack((points, np.ones((points.shape[0], 1)))) # add w-dim to points
    projected_points = mvp @ points.T # project points to 2D
    normalized_projected_points = (
        np.array(
            [
                projected_points[0] / projected_points[2],  # This step scales the projected points by the z-axis to clip-space. 
                projected_points[1] / projected_points[2],
            ]
        )
        + 1 # adding +1 and multiplying by 0.5 simply scales [-1, 1] to [0, 1] making easier to scale to the image resolution later
    ) * 0.5
    clipped_points = normalized_projected_points[
        :,
        (normalized_projected_points[0] >= 0)
        & (normalized_projected_points[0] < 1)
        & (normalized_projected_points[1] >= 0)
        & (normalized_projected_points[1] < 1),
    ].T # This step removes all points outside of clip-space
    scaled_projected_points = (clipped_points * resolution).astype(np.int32) # scale to the actual resolution
    scaled_projected_points[:, 1] = 1 - scaled_projected_points[:, 1] # invert y-axis since PIL starts from top

    img = np.zeros(shape=(resolution[1], resolution[0], 3), dtype=np.uint8) #  start with a black image
    img[scaled_projected_points [:, 1], scaled_projected_points [:, 0]] = (255, 255, 255) # color all pixel white based on the coordinates given by the projection. 
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(img)
    pil_img.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

As said, the above code produces the same shape as the blender render, only if I scale the projection matrix approximately like this:
[[ 2.8060329*0.8    0.              0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.               3.74137735*0.8  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.               0.             -1.00019991 -0.20002   ]
 [ 0.               0.             -1.          0.        ]]

EDIT
For completion, here is the render output from blender:

And the ouput of the 3D->2D project (with the scaled projection matrix)

1944/2592 = 0.75 :)

You need to account for the difference in X,Y because the result of the camera projection is mapped to [0,1];[0,1] whereas going to say 0.5 in the X axis won't cover the same number of pixels than going to 0.5 in the Y axis

BTW have you explored bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view ? With it you shouldn't have to mess with camera and projection matrices, fill in the scene, camera object and 3d coordinate to get the 2D point. You do have to remap the 2D point.

@Gorgious thank you, but the 0.75 factor is already incoorporated in the projection matrix I get from blender (3.74137735 * 0.75 = 2.8060329), so I don't think that is what I have been looking for. Actually I have to scale booth these numbers be 0.8 to get the correct result.

Additionally, I didn't mention it (since the post was already long enough :) ), but the reason for all of this is a bigger project, where we want to use blender to simulate camera data. For this I have to match the real world settings with the simulated ones closely, that is the reason for this effort to work with those matrices externally and trying to match the results.

It turns out there where two bugs in my code above.
One minor, which had the needed effect, but created a pixel offset of one pixel
Buggy part:
scaled_projected_points[:, 1] = 1 - scaled_projected_points[:, 1]

This inversion must be done before scaling the points to the image resolution:
clipped_points[:, 1] = 1 - clipped_points[:, 1]
scaled_projected_points = (clipped_points * resolution).astype(np.int32)

But the major error was the "per-point" scaling by the z-axis. Instead of the z-axis, one has to scale by the w-axis. So after changing this part:
normalized_projected_points = (
    np.array(
        [
            projected_points[0] / projected_points[2],
            projected_points[1] / projected_points[2],
        ]
    )
    + 1
) * 0.5


to
normalized_projected_points = (
    np.array(
        [
            projected_points[0] / projected_points[3],
            projected_points[1] / projected_points[3],
        ]
    )
    + 1
) * 0.5

The images produced by blender match the 3D->2D projection perfectly. I tested this with various different camera positions and rotations as well as different positions and rotations of the contour object.
